# Choose individual startup visibility of org-mode's source blocks

Tags: org-mode, org-babel

In `org-mode`, how could one specify the visibility state of individual SRC_BLOCKs when a file is opened?

`org-mode` provides the variable `org-hide-block-startup` to specify if all source blocks are shown or hidden when a file is opened. How could I specify, instead, the initial state of individual source blocks when a file is opened?

The visibility state of headings can be manually chosen using the `VISIBILITY` property. It is not obvious, however, if there is something similar for source blocks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Indeed, some code blocks are too long and take up too much space.

By default, you want to display all the code blocks, only hidden when you set a block of code to hide.

Suppose there is a block of code in an org file that needs to be hidden, like:

```
#+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp :hidden
(defun individual-visibility-source-blocks ()
  "Fold some blocks in the current buffer."
  (interactive)
  (org-show-block-all)
  (org-block-map
   (lambda ()
     (let ((case-fold-search t))
       (when (and
              (save-excursion
                (beginning-of-line 1)
                (looking-at org-block-regexp))
              (cl-assoc
               ':hidden
               (cl-third
                (org-babel-get-src-block-info))))
         (org-hide-block-toggle))))))

(add-hook
 'org-mode-hook
 (function individual-visibility-source-blocks))
#+END_SRC
```

When the command "individual-visibility-source-blocks" is used, all code blocks are displayed except for the code block.

Comment: Your answer is nice and clever. You've made me aware of the function `org-block-map` which I'm sure will me put to use in many other places.

Comment: This works fine. However, it  doesn't work if <language> is missing in the block header. eg `#+BEGIN_SRC  :hidden`

Comment: @dips You are picking the bones in the egg. "(error "No such language mode: :hidden-mode")". Try `#+BEGIN_EXAMPLE` blocks, but that is not the answer to this question.

Comment: @SunDawning, would you consider contributing this upstream so that it is a standard feature of org-mode?

Comment: @SunDawning sorry to nag. Is this something you'd be willing to contribute upstream? If not, would you be ok with me contributing it to org-mode? This is a nice feature and something I think many people could benefit from. Thanks.

Comment: +1 for upstream contribution!